# Java - Swing - Update a JTable with user input, the JTable isn't visible

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I'm practicing with JTables and I'm looking at the documentation as well for JTables at Oracle's J 7's library. What I'm working on is getting user input and display it in a JTable, simple.

My code currently is:

```
public class tablePractice {
    
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Table Test");
    JPanel panel=new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
    
    JLabel username=new JLabel("Username: ");
    JTextField nameField=new JTextField(10);
    JButton add=new JButton("Add");
    
    JTable table=new JTable();
    JScrollPane scrollPane=new JScrollPane();

    DefaultTableModel model=new DefaultTableModel();
    ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
    
    public void setInterface() {
        
        frame.setSize(300,300);
        
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setContentPane(panel);
        panel.add(username);
        panel.add(nameField);
        
        
        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource()==add) {
                    list.add(nameField.getText());
                    model.addRow(list.toArray());
                    System.out.println(list);
                }
            }
        });
        panel.add(add);
        table.setModel(model);
        table.add(scrollPane);
        panel.add(table);
        
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        tablePractice run=new tablePractice();
        run.setInterface();
    }
}
```

[image: Frame2]
And the list is printed on the console but I have no JTable present.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `JTable` needs to be contained *within* the scrollpane

```
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
// table.add(scrollPane); don't do this
panel.add(scrollPane);
```

Also you need to define the columns for your model. E.g.

```
model.addColumn("Name");
```

then add a row

```
// model.addRow(list.toArray()); varible-length row - don't do this
model.addRow(new Object[] { nameField.getText() });
```

Comment: Hello @Reimeus, thank you for your help. I tried your method:
scrollPane.setViewportView(table);panel.add(scrollPane); but I see no difference, the JTable doesnt appear.

Comment: Oh I just saw your new edit of the answer, Ignore my previous comment, I will work on it and post the results.

Comment: Thank you for the info, flagged your answer as the solution.

Answer (score -1):

You want to display it? Then you just need to create a new Label with your input text and add this label to your panel.

````
add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if(e.getSource()==add) {
                    model.addRow(list.toArray());
                    JLabel text = new JLabel(nameField.getText());
                    panel.add(text);
                }
            }
        });```
````

Comment: Hello Diana, thank you for your answer. Well I'm looking to print the input stored in the JTextField with the getText() method and display it in a JTable. Currently with your method I get to print it in a JLabel. (not what I needed)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).